# Text Editor with Color input in react js

Tags: reactjs, input, decode, text-editor

How to get a input like this using text editor and not to have a tool box in it.
[I want input with different highlighting colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKuoU.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.